# Background images path in Compass

Tags: compass-sass, compass

I have a question related to background image url in Compass. I generated a sprite and I have the following path **"images/social/facebook.png"** but compass generated the sprite in the folder "images" **(images/social-s17cf54cdde.png)**. When I inspect the element in the site I noticed that the background url isn't correct. I need to access one level up (../) so instead of **"background-image: url('/images/social-s17cf54cdde.png');"** I need **"background-image: url('../images/social-s17cf54cdde.png');"**. How can I do that?

In the scss file I used these code:

```
@import "social/*.png"; 
@include all-social-sprites;
```